# $unset not removing property as expected in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

The document in the collection Programs has the following structure

```
{
  ...
  "Students" : {
    "Friday" : {
        "DUETS" : [
            "", 
            ""
        ], 
        "JOHN MCKEON" : [
            "", 
            ""
        ], 
        "TERRY STARR" : [
            "", 
            ""
        ], 
        "REBECCA SAWYER-FAY" : [
            "", 
            ""
        ]
    }, 
    "Thursday" : {
        "SIOBHAN ARMSTRONG" : [
            "", 
            ""
        ], 
        "REBECCA SAWYER-FAY" : [
            "", 
            ""
        ], 
        "CHERYL RITZ" : [
            "", 
            ""
        ], 
        "CLARE DELANEY" : [
            "", 
            ""
        ]
    }, 
    "Tuesday" : {
        "JOHN MCKEON" : [
            "", 
            ""
        ]
    }, 
    "Wednesday" : {
        "LOIS ROSS" : [
            "9:00", 
            "10:00"
        ], 
        "ANNE DICKINSON" : [
            "10:00", 
            "11:00"
        ], 
        "BECKY HOWARD" : [
            "11:00", 
            "12:00"
        ], 
        "MAX LUCAS" : [
            "", 
            ""
        ]
    }
  },
  ....
}
```

If I wanted to remove the Monday property, I can do it like this and it works as expected.

```
Programs.update({ _id: id }, { $unset: { 'Students.Monday': "" }});
```

But I'm having trouble removing a property one layer deeper. If I wanted to remove 'DUETS' in 'Friday', for example.

I'm trying what I think would work:

```
Programs.update({ _id: id}, { $unset: { 'Students.Friday.DUETS': "" }});
```

I'm not having success with this. What should work?

Comment: From [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14421143/1377864) I would assume your error is in some other place. Are you sure you selecting/checking correct entity?

Comment: I think you're right. Problem is elsewhere. My function that is calling the update is not running as planned.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove like this:

```
db.collection.update({}, {$unset: {"Students.Friday.DUETS": 1}}, false, true);
```